# Deleting the most recent submission from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to know how you can delete the most recent submission.

Lets say I submit some info to my database.

I have two columns in my database, one called "id" which increments everytime you add an item to the database and one called "checked" which stores the info of the items checked.

On my website after you click submit, it goes to some page and shows what you just submitted.

What I want is for them to have the option to delete that submission if they want.

Problem is how do I delete the most recent submission (like the whole row) without altering the other submission in the database.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
<?php
   session_start();
   require('config.php');

   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
         $id = $_SESSION['delete'];
          $sql = "DELETE FROM list WHERE checked=$id"; //"checked" is the column name
     }
```

Also

```
$_SESSION['delete'] = .$checked //This is in the other file which stores the checked name
```

I know this isn't right and it doesn't work but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: is the session array/`$id` a string?

Comment: `$_SESSION['delete'] = .$checked` looks like an error, is that your real code?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah it holds a string and that is from my code, use another one just like it to display the data I just submitted

Comment: you've an answer below now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysqli_insert_id()` to get the last record inserted and set it in the session. And then delete that record when needed.

```
$_SESSION['last_id']=mysqli_insert_id($conn);


$last_id=$_SESSION['last_id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM list WHERE checked=$id AND id=$last_id ";
```

Comment: $conn is mysqli connection object, you must be having the same object with other name.